# Full screen css layout

Tags: css, layout, fullscreen

I want to create a full screen css layout.

```
<div id="divLeft">LEFT is ok</div>
<div id="divRight">
    <div id="divTop">TOP is ok</div>
    <div id="divCenter">CENTER should have liquid height</div>
    <div id="divBottom">BOTTOM should be always bottom</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html{
     height:100%
}
body{
    height:100%
}
#divLeft{
    float:left;
    width:70px;
    height:100%;
    background:#6c9;
}
#divRight{
   margin-left:70px;
    height:100%;
    background:#999;
    color:#fff;
}
#divTop{
     background:red;
     text-align:right;
}
#divCenter{
      background:blue;
      text-align:center;
}
#divBottom{
  background:green;
  text-align:center;
}
```

[Here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bonaca/gpwD4/4/)

So, problem is with the `#divCenter` (should have liquid height) and `#divBottom` (should be always at the bottom of the screen).

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/gpwD4/5/

Comment: @SunSky try with `position:absolute` and bottom 0px like http://jsfiddle.net/Bonaca/gpwD4/4/ ..Adrift fiddle is much better :)

Comment: @Adrift nice work, you should post it as answer :)

Comment: @Adrift, excellent, just one thing - how to place `#divCenter` content verticaly centered ?

Comment: Do you plan on adding any other elements within `#divCenter`?

Comment: @Adrift, yes, it should be an image slider :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this easily with the [`calc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation) function, though it isn't [supported below IE 9](http://caniuse.com/calc) and mobile support is quite bad. All you need to do is give `#divCenter` a height of 100% minus the 20px + 20px of height from its siblings. To have the footer appear on the bottom, you need to relatively position its containing block and then absolutely position the footer and place it at the bottom (`bottom: 0;`).

http://jsfiddle.net/gpwD4/6/

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `#divTop` and `#divBottom` have fixed heights, you can do this:

```
#divRight{
   position: relative;
}

#divCenter{
   position: absolute;
   top: (height of #divTop)
   bottom: (height of #divBottom)
   left:0;
   right:0;

}
#divBottom{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XJsXu/)